# DateTime calculations with TimeOnly struct

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-6.0

First of all, I love the idea of seperate [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly) and [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly) structs, which are available in .NET 6 and allow for a cleaner usage of `System.DateTime`.

I was wondering: Is it possible to calculate with DateTime and e.g. TimeOnly?

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("2021-01-01 10:00") - TimeOnly.Parse("10:00");
// result == DateTime.Parse("2021-01-01")?
```

Does this even make sense?

Comment: Probably not since we already have `TimsSpan` for adding/subtracting an amount of time from a `DateTime`.   subtracting a time of day from a date/time doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You can't subtract a time from a DateTime because the concept does not make any sense. You can subtract a duration. In your example you could say that you would like to *remove* the time component from DateTime, but this could easily be done using just `.Date` on `DateTime`. Instead you should subtract a TimeSpan which specifies a *duration*, this concept makes sense.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("10:00")` doesn't make sense either. You can't talk about a date whose value is 10AM - on what day?. You *can* subtract two `TimeOnly` values and get back a duration, ie TimeSpan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think OP used that just for the MRE (that operation results in 10am of current date), as the comment says that they expect the result to be the today date.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. But to clarify the situation, I have updated my question to fix the compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no overload of `-` that takes a `DateTime` and a `TimeOnly`. However, `TimeOnly` has a `.ToTimeSpan()` method, so you can do like this:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("10:00") - TimeOnly.Parse("10:00").ToTimeSpan();
```